# ModuleNotFoundError when running playbook on Ubuntu/Ansible

Tags: python, azure, ubuntu, ansible

I have Ansible installed on Ubuntu 18.04 (on Windows with WSL). Ansible has to run playbooks to manage Azure. When I try to run a playbook (for creating a VNET) I get an error:

`An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.common' fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to import the required Python library (ansible[azure] (azure >= 2.0.0)) on XPS15's Python /usr/bin/python3. Please read the module documentation and install it in the appropriate location. If the required library is installed, but Ansible is using the wrong Python interpreter, please consult the documentation on ansible_python_interpreter"}`

I tried different things, like installing Ansible on different ways (also with pip). Installing different versions of Python. Installed different versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: Have you tried installing `azure` which appears to be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Ansible installation is missing the Azure module.

Refering to [the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/scenario_guides/guide_azure.html), you can install it with the command below.

```
pip install 'ansible[azure]'
```

Comment: Thanks alot! It is working now. Missed this crucial step